# Equation of smooth spline curve

Tags: transformation, spline

This is a homework question

> a)Assume an equilateral triangle ABC of a side AB = a = 10.The coordinate of A is (5, 3).The slope of the segment AB is 2.This triangle controls a curve.This smooth curve starts from the center of gravity G of the triangle with a slope 1.0 and is tangent at two points on segments AB and AC.These points are at 1/3a from B an C on segments AB and AC.Determine the equations for the smooth spline curve.
>
> b)Assume the same triangle in 3 dimensions.The Z coordinates for each point is zero (Z = 0) to start with.This triangle is rotated by an angle 30 degree about the axis formed by the cord joining points A and C keeping center of gravity of triangle fixed.Determine the required transformation to rotate the triangle and spline curve.

please tell how to start solving this problem!!

Comment: Start by drawing this triangle on the XY Cartesian plane. Calculate the points which should be on the slope and add them to the graph. Publish this image along with your question, in order to make it a little easier on other users to answer your question. Once you have $3$ or more points, computing a Spline is relatively easy (if you don't know how, then it can be shown to you in the answer).

Comment: What kinds of spline curves do you know about? Cubic only? Have you ever heard of Lagrange interpolation, or Hermite interpolation? Do you know how to construct a spline curve from given points and slopes?